# htaccess file not working, can't access php files in subfolders

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp, laragon

Im using htaccess file to have shorter links for subdomains in my website project. It was working in previous envinorment just fine, but now on new PC (fresh xampp and laragon install), it's not working as intended.
I want to be able to access `http://localhost/poradnik/smart` (poradnik\pages\smart.php)
but i get a 404 error and the subwebsite cant be opened.

my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} of
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z-_0-9]+)?$ index.php?page=$1/$2 [L]

SetEnv BASEURL "https://localhost/poradnik/"
```

And my file branch is as follows:
[file list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm4DC.png)

Comment: Your sample url has http, your rewrite rules have https?

Comment: Have you tried going to `http://localhost/poradnik/pages/smart` to see if that works?